# Calling the location of ActiveX Object in VBA PPT - Invalid Quantifier

Tags: vba, powerpoint

As we know that Slide Number and Slide Name is different, we use the Slide Number to call shapes and we use the Slide Name to call ActiveX Objects in PowerPoint

I can use `ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlideNo).Shapes("CA").TextFrame.TextRange` to find the text within that shape.

I can't use the same to find the value of the TextBox (ActiveX Object). I would have to do something like `Slide3.TextBox1.Value`.

```
Dim CurrentSlideNo As Integer
CurrentSlideNo = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex

Dim CurrentSlideName As String
CurrentSlideName = ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlideNo).Name

MsgBox CurrentSlideName.TextBox1.Value
```

I tried doing the above but it clearly didn't work. I get the error of an Invalid Qualifier. 
I would be highly obliged if someone can guide me here. Thank you!

I am able to get the name of the slide as a string. I am just unable to convert it into a Quantifier.

`MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.TextBox1.Value` did not allow me to get the `value` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

```
MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Value
```